# OpenGL plugin crashes Chrome when the visible region is changed

Tags: google-chrome, opengl, npapi, firebreath

I'm developing a plugin using FireBreath on Windows (for now) that among other things is displaying a webcam feed using OpenGL. I'm using a windowed plugin and I'm drawing from a separate thread. The code can be viewed here:

Header file

https://github.com/EvilTengil/kinect-at-home-plugin/blob/0007beecf136ff2e5e1aa50be94d4906447a8f43/Win/KinectAtHomeWin.h

Source file

https://github.com/EvilTengil/kinect-at-home-plugin/blob/0007beecf136ff2e5e1aa50be94d4906447a8f43/Win/KinectAtHomeWin.cpp

(Ignore the strange code in onWindowResized, it's just some testing that remained in the commit.)

The problem is that as soon as the browser window is re-sized so that the visible region of the plugin is changed or the the extension is somehow scrolled outside the visible area of the scroll box, the plugin crashes in Chrome. I haven't got Firefox installed but I'm guessing it's a NpApi thing, since it's working in Internet Explorer.

I believe what is happening is that Chrome releases and creates a new HDC whenever the visible dimensions of the plugin is changed. This probably results in that the Rendering Context is invalid, but it is still being used in the plugin and that causes the crash.

I've noticed NPP_SetWindow get's called when this happens, but those calls are ignored in NpapiPluginModule_NPP.cpp, so my there is no way of hooking in to this event.

I've Google for several hours now but without finding any help. Does anyone have any experience of this?

I have an idea that it could work if I created my own child window to the plugin window where I could handle my own DC. I did some quick testing that failed, which is probably because of my lame Win32 skills. But could this work with some more work? Another idea I have is to track the visible region somehow, but I haven't looked in to this yet.

Comment: Had a quick look at this but no time to dig deeper. It's enough to just setup OGL without drawing, happening in FF and Chrome and not happening in FF when out-of-process-plugins are disabled. Disabling FBs window subclassing doesn't help. Attach Visual Studio with the Microsoft symbol server configured (possibly [Mozillas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Mozilla_symbol_server) too) and you'll see that it crashes with a stack overflow in some window process handling (infinite recursion apparently). BTW, `SetWindow` goes through `FB::NpapiPluginWin` here.

Answer (score 1):

Windows handles getting invalid should not cause a program to crash per so. But OpenGL, namely its extensions require some special precautions, especially if the host program makes use of OpenGL as well.

Any kind of plugin or DLL that makes use of OpenGL must take care, that is puts its required resources into a sane state before using them, and put them back once done. For OpenGL this means, everytime before you start using it you should rebind your context:

```
HDC hOldDC = wglGetCurrentDC();
HRC hOldContext = wglGetCurrentContext();

 // first unbind old context/DC from current thread
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);

 // then bind our context
wglMakeCurrent(hMyDC, hMyContext);

 // this is essential, as in Windows the addresses of extensions
 // may depend on the active context, so you must reinitialise
 // extension function pointers!
reinitialize_extensions();

/* NOW USE OPENGL FUNCTION

 // cleaning up once we're done:
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
wglMakeCurrent(hOldDC, hOldRC);
// remember that we also need to reset extension
// function pointers to the other context
reinitialize_extensions();
```

Since in Window extension functions pointers depend on the context it makes sense to put them into a structure and call them through that one. This saves the whole extension reinitialisation thing. In C++ you could wrap the whole OpenGL context in a class for this.

Remember that you need to go through this setup/teardown everytime your plugin gets called through NP-API.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you actually have trouble because of invalidated extensions pointers ? I've been doing GL on Windows for years without trouble with this, but I may have been lucky because of dedicated hardware, and not messing too often with multiple simultaneous contexts.

Comment: The OP has the OpenGL setup & drawing code in a separate thread and [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374387(v=vs.85).aspx) say that you get one current GL context per thread

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche: If the OP followed my advice, he gets multithreading support with it as well. The point about OpenGL multithreading is, that a context must be active in only one thread at a time, and that each thread has exactly one context. But a context can perfectly migrate between threads. Above code will also take care of multi thread safety.

Comment: Hm, that's what i gathered as well, but he creates a new context on a new thread, never migrating anything or activating another context on that thread. For reference: i added the above to a repro-case and it doesn't change the behaviour here

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche: Oh, so that means he tries to set the PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR on the same window multiple times? That could be part of the reason, since a window's PFD can, actually must be set only once.

Comment: At least with Firefox it's only once, i assume Chrome behaving roughly the same. As per my comment on the question, it looks like the browsers and WGLs window processes might interfere with each other.